# Callback function never called after Mongoose query is executed

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

The following is my code:

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/mydatabase');
  var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', function callback () {
  console.log('DB connection opened');
});
// ...
var dbCallback = function(err, body) {
  // ...
};
// ...
var StuffModel = mongoose.model('Stuff', StuffSchema);
StuffModel.find({}).exec(dbCallback);
```

The `dbCallback` function is never called. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Have you tried doing your query *after* the database connection opens? I don't have a Mongoose server to test it, but that would be my first guess.

```
var Stuff = mongoose.model('Stuff', StuffSchema);

db.once('open', function () {
  Stuff.find({}, function (e, body) {
    console.log('It worked!');
  });
});
```

Sorry, if this doesn't end up fixing it.

Comment: The query is being run after the database connection opens, but I'll check if querying from inside the db callback will change anything.

Answer (score 7):

Make sure that you are actually connected to your Mongo instance, otherwise queries will be left hanging and often no error is thrown or returned. An error in my Mongo URI was causing this for me.

In your code, you have your Mongo URI set to `mongodb://localhost/mydatabase`. I imagine that this is probably not correct and is the cause of your problem. Change your URI to just `localhost:27017`, which is the default port that Mongo is set to run on.

Comment: This is actually really helpful. If there's a problem with your mongo uri you don't get any response or error from mongoose.connect()

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue.

I was calling `process.exit(0)` after queries, so the app exited before mongoose have a chance to run callback.

So i removed `process.exit(0)` and it worked!