# mongoose findOne data does not exit not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

user_id 2 does not exist in mongodb  but console log does not print 'does not exist'

```
var query = PostData.findOne({ 'user_id': '2'});

query.exec(function (err, doc) {
  if(doc) {
    console.log('ok');
  } else {
    console.log('does not exist');
  }
});
```

Without mongoose it works:

```
connection.db.collection("PostData", function(err, collection){
   collection.find({ 'user_id': '2'}).toArray(function(err, data){
      console.log(data); // it will print your collection data
   })
});
```

prints `[]`

Comment: What about `err`? Is it set? Which version of mongoose are you using?

Comment: Version 4.11.7 * err  = handle Error

Comment: Can  you log the error?  `if (err) {
console.log(err);
        return;
    }; if(doc) {
    console.log('ok');
  } else {
    console.log('does not exist');
  }`

Comment: no errors, recode not function  the function exit; because  I put  var query = PostData.findOne({ 'user_id': '2'});

query.exec(function (err, doc) { console.log('test')
  if(doc) {
    console.log('ok');
  } else {
    console.log('does not exist');
  }
});  test also not print

Comment: Must be something else then, are you sure you have an open mongo connection? Try read this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21894050/callback-function-never-called-after-mongoose-query-is-executed

Comment: PostData.findOne({ 'user_id': '1'}); data loding but PostData.findOne({ 'user_id': '2'});  empty result not showing.

Answer (score 0):

No matter an object exists or not , MongoDB is going to return an array anyway. If the object exists, they array will be filled with it otherwise it's just an empty array. So if you want to check if the user exists or not you must check for `doc.length` , if it's 0 then it means the user doesn't exist.

Comment: Could you tell me how you changed the code? Please post it here

Comment: Finaly  I used count method to fixed the issue  PostData.findOne({ 'user_id': '1', "created_at": { $gte: today}}).count

Comment: @Nimesha if you only need to confirm user existence, your method is better . But if you also need to return the found user , then this will not work.